# How to disable an extension in TYPO3

Tags: plugins, typo3

Because I want to try out another extension I would have two extensions which will conflict each other. Therefore I want to disable an extension temporary. If I find out that I would need the old extension again I want to enable it.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

I think `Remove Extension` would completely remove the extension. Should I edit the `localconf.php`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Extension Manager` for this, it will **NOT** remove files and databases, just will modify the `localconf.php` to disable extension. After test you can safely turn it on the same way.

Try to avoid any operations like `Database Compare` in the install tool while testing as you can accidentally delete tables of that disabled extension.

Comment: So that means I should do the following: Extension Manager -> Install extension -> Click on the icon before the extension name on `Remove Extension`?

Comment: Yes, in both directions (install/remove).

Comment: The "Remove Extension" label is quite misleading. It's really only uninstall. Removal of the extension is done in another step after uninstallation in the "Maintenance" (TYPO3 4.5.x) tab of the extension.

Comment: In addtion, the extension's custom configuration and all the data remain unaltered. It's really more like a enable/disable button.